# Dot at start and end using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Hello I am trying to validate an input using regex in Javascript, what my requirement is that I can have at most **one dot** ('.') in the string and **that can't be at the start and end**. 
I got a solution in

```
/^[^\.].*[^\.]$/;
```

But the issue is input **"x" is considered as invalid**
valid inputs are like
"x", "x.x", "xx.x" , "x.xx" like so
invalid like ".x" and "x."

Comment: Rule #763476 on how to write maintainable code: if you don't know how do smth with regex do not do it with regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

`/^(?!\.)[^\.]*\.?[^\.]*(?!\.).$/`

Answer (score 1):

With your current regex, you are targeting a string that should be at least 2 characters long, as both [^\.] parts are a mandatory character.

Your regex should include an extra check in case there is just one character, which you can do like this:
`^([^\.]|([^\.]+\.?[^\.]+))$`

Comment: This seems to allow multiple dots though.

Comment: You're right. I've updated the expression to allow only 1 dot.

Comment: Hey, values like `'xx'` fail... `?`

Comment: eh, I forgot to make the dot optional after changing the \.* to \.

Answer (score 1):

The correct regex for

> my requirement is that I can have at most one dot ('.') in the string
>   and that can't be at the start and end

is

```
/^([^\.]|([^\.]*.?[^\.]))$/
```

> `/^([^\.]|([^\.].*[^\.]))$/` or `/^[^\.].*[^\.]$/` accepts String
>   containing more than 1 dot . Hence it will also accept X..X too.

Please check working snippet also

```js
   

    validateString("XX.X");
    validateString("X.X");
    validateString("X...X");
    validateString("X");
    validateString("X.X.X");

    validateString(".XX");

    validateString("XX.");

    function validateString(str){
      console.log(/^([^\.]|([^\.]*.?[^\.]))$/.test(str));
    }
```

Comment: Your regex `/^([^\.]|([^\.]*.?[^\.]))$/` fails for values like `'.x'` and `'x.xx'` so more work is required yet...